# python: urllib.request.urlopen not working

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have a problem with urllib request because it throws this error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

the code I am using is this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url='https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148717266'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

The whole error log is this:

```
    HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3be7085b64e6> in <module>
      5 
      6 url='https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148717266'
----> 7 html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
      8 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Any help I would really apreciate!
thanks before hand

Comment: if you're getting a 5XX error, it means the _server_ has an internal error. It is something you will have very limited control over. The way to debug this is to check the request you're sending, simplifying it to the minimum of parameters until it works, or it can't get simpler. Using a tool like postman may help with that. But most likely, you need to request help from the owner of the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `User-Agent` header in your request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

req = Request('https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148717266')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0')
content = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Documento - 37/8e/3a04fd80aee93aeeb325f0ff8fa06e0a4634
  </title>

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. I didn't know about User-agent request, now I am learning!